# Pattern matching inside of struct

Tags: rust

I want to use a pattern match to check the inside of a struct without building a new struct. I am trying to swap value of the struct as an exercise (I know `mem::swap` exists).

Swapping means matching a value of the struct and then swapping the matching values. Like let `x = {10,20,30}; x.swap(10,30)` should yield `{30,20,10}`.

What I want to be able to, but can't

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct Color {
    r: u8,
    g: u8,
    b: u8,
    a: u8,
}

impl Color {
    fn swap(mut self, first: u8, second: u8) -> Color {
        match (first) {
            self.r => {
                match (second) {
                    self.b => {
                        self.r = second;
                        self.b = first;
                    },
                    self.g => {
                        self.r = second;
                        self.g = first;
                    },
                    self.a => {
                        self.r = second;
                        self.a = first;
                    },
                    _ => {},
                }
            },
            _ => {}
        }

        Color {
            r: self.r,
            g: self.g,
            b: self.b,
            a: self.a,
        }
    }
}
fn main() {
    let c = Color {
        r: 255,
        g: 200,
        b: 10,
        a: 30,
    };

    let color = c.swap(c.r, c.a);

    println!("{:?}", color);
}
```

The code is not valid, it is what I would like to accomplish. Is there a way to do this? I assume I am way off base on this approach.

Comment: What does `{10,20,10,20}.swap(10, 20)` yield? How about `{10,10,10,20}.swap(10, 20)`

Comment: This is an exercise on matching inner structs which is all I really care about, but that would keep switching all the matches all the way down.

Comment: Are you already aware that `match` takes one and only one arm?

Comment: I was not, but that is ideal. I am admittedly a complete novice. Actually that is the only thing that makes sense or _ => would always evaluate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, there is a way to do this with pattern matching, but you'd likely never see this in practice. The missing piece is to use a [match guard](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/book/second-edition/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#extra-conditionals-with-match-guards):

```
match first {
    v if v == self.r => {
        match second {
            v if v == self.b => {
                self.r = second;
                self.b = first;
            },
            v if v == self.g => {
                self.r = second;
                self.g = first;
            },
            v if v == self.a => {
                self.r = second;
                self.a = first;
            },
            _ => {},
        }
    },
    _ => {}
}
```

But this isn't really using any useful part of pattern matching; it's just a bunch of if else clauses:

```
if first == self.r {
    if second == self.b {
        self.r = second;
        self.b = first;
    } else if second == self.g {
        self.r = second;
        self.g = first;
    } else if second == self.a {
        self.r = second;
        self.a = first;
    }
}
```

You could choose to shoehorn in some patterns though:

```
let x1 = (first == self.r, first == self.g, first == self.b, first == self.a);
let x2 = (second == self.r, second == self.g, second == self.b, second == self.a);

match (x1, x2) {
    ((true, _, _, _), (_, true, _, _)) => {
        self.r = second;
        self.b = first;
        }
    ((true, _, _, _), (_, _, true, _)) => {
        self.r = second;
        self.g = first;
        }
    ((true, _, _, _), (_, _, _, true)) => {
        self.r = second;
        self.a = first;
    }
    _ => {}
}
```

Comment: Awesome.  I knew my method was not the way to do it but I was curious if you could do it. I keep thinking of matches as a Switch Case but I guess it is slightly different.

Comment: @MitchellIngram thinking of it as a C `switch` isn't a bad first approximation.  However, C's `switch` doesn't allow a `case` with a dynamic value, so perhaps I'm misunderstanding you?

Comment: Like this: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FF37RNWZZH5E

Comment: @MitchellIngram ah, a JS `switch`; yes, Rust is reasonably different from that because the matched patterns have to be statically checked.

Comment: Makes sense, just going to take a bit to get used to. Always excited to learn. Thanks for the help!